# How to create an <input> using document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I try the follow  -

```
var input = document.createElement("<input type='checkbox' name='test'>")
```

but it prompt -

```
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters.
```

I use `Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 m`

Comment: See the doc http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-2141741547

Comment: MDN usually has nice explanation of DOM methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create the plain element and then add the attributes:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "checkbox";
input.name = "test";
```

Comment: You could also use input.setAttribute('type','checkbox'). That way you can set all attributes you want.

Comment: This is _not_ setting attributes, it is setting shorthand attribute properties, i.e. properties that reflect attribute values. @NickySmits Shorthand properties are to be preferred; one notable exception are `data-*` attributes, and attributes in XML namespaces.

Comment: I know what you are saying. but both methods work. And if the person decides to add some onclick action, he could do it within a string, which might be easier than an anonymous function (since this person is learning the basics)

Answer (score 0):

The document.createElement function takes a tag name for the element you want to create (in your case input)

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
```

you can then access attributes for that element like so:

```
input.type = "checkbox";
input.name = "test";
```

Here is another question with the same answer:
[How to create <input type=“text”/> dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656392/how-to-create-input-type-text-dynamically)