# File validation in HTML using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have on file control that accept only pdf file. and i want to validate file that accept only pdf file as well as if another file is selected than recreate the file control in div tag with same name as well as same id.

validation must be javascript or jquery.

```
 ...
 <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" />
 </div>
 ...
```

Comment: i have try to validate file using javascript but not able to do.

Comment: You can use jqueryvalidate plugin for this. Used it before it's pretty simple.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<input name="file" type="file" accept="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: as per your suggestion...you can change file type when file dialog box is open

Comment: I think there is no way to do validation in the client. You can check through  extension only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#file1").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'pdf':
            alert("Correct type");
            //your code
            break;
        default:
            // error message here
            alert("not a PDF file");
            //yourcode
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: this only check the extension and not the filetype

Comment: @rikpg checking extension is better solution validation. There is no other way to check file type in Jquery.

Comment: the OP can use File API to do some stuff on client side, check this out: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: your file validation is right..but when i select file except pdf..then file control is not created in div.

Comment: @AmitMaru if you select file except pdf them `not a PDF file` alerts. Here you have to code for creating new file control, it will not create automatically.

Comment: @Manwal ya right..but i dont know how to create file control using javascript if i am not select pdf file.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5656401/2236219. Same as this code you can create file input also.