# How do I generate a list of textboxes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a JS application that automatically another textbox on user input. I'm not however sure how I append an `input` to a `li`

The end result I want to get at is this:

```
<ul id="lst">
  <li>Item1: <input type="text"></li>
  <li>Item2: <input type="text"></li>
  <!-- more li added on button press -->
</ul>
```

what I got so far is this:

```
var onClick = function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('lst'),
      li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item' + counter + ': '));
  counter++;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

How do I also append the `<input type="text">` node?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5656401/4298881. Construct a input node and append it after you append the Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you added the text to the element.

```
var onClick = function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('lst'),
      li = document.createElement('li'),
      input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type="text";
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item' + counter + ': '));
  li.appendChild(input);
  counter++;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use a `label` element as well, and append that along with an `input`

```
var onClick = function() {
    var ul    = document.getElementById('lst'),
        li    = document.createElement('li'),
        label = document.createElement('label'),
        input = document.createElement('input');

    label.text = "Item " + counter + ":";
    li.appendChild(label);
    //input.type = "text";
    li.appendChild(input); //defaults to type text
    ul.appendChild(li);

    counter++;
}
```