# How can I generate multiple inputs upon user's request?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate multiple `<input type=text>` based on user's request. In another word, the user enters a number, like `n` and therefore `<input type=text>` going to appear on the screen for `n` times.

Here is my code, which somehow is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656401/5556365), but doesn't work properly for me.

```js
function generateInputs() {
  var count = document.getElementById("test");

  for (i = 0; i < Number(count); i++) {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass");
      x[0].appendChild(input)
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="number" id="test" min="2" max="20" required>
    <button onclick="generateInputs()">Test</button>

    <div class="testClass">    
    </div>
</body>
```

I expect to see for example 2 `<input ...>`, if the user enters 2 and clicks the button, but nothing is shown.
Would you mind let me know about my mistake?

Comment: Use `var count = document.getElementById("test").value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really close. The thing is that you're not getting the count correctly. You're getting the **element**, not its **value**. Add `.value`:

```
var count = document.getElementById("test").value;
// ----------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

There are a few other things to consider as well:

1. You're not declaring `i`, so the code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables. :-)
2. Probably best to convert `value` from string to number just once, rather than on each iteration of the loop.
3. Similarly, there's no reason to go get the `.testClass` elements every time in the loop.
4. `type` is reflected as an element property, so if you like, instead of

   ```
   input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
   ```

   you can use

   ```
   input.type = 'text';
   ```

Comment: Off topic but I find it incredible that after 20+ years `document.getElementById` is still being used. I wouldn't be surprised if I saw it being used in 2030 or beyond.

Comment: I'd like to add that most of the problems listed in this answer could be avoided by using jshint and strict(er) type checking (via TypeScript or `.jshintrc`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the *value* from the *input* element. You also do not need to get the element (to where the append is to be made) in each iteration:

```
var count = document.getElementById("test").value;
```

```js
function generateInputs() {
  var count = document.getElementById("test").value;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass");
  for (i = 0; i < Number(count); i++) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    x[0].appendChild(input)
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="number" id="test" min="2" max="20" required />
  <button onclick="generateInputs()">Test</button>
  <div class="testClass"></div>
</body>
```